What exactly constitutes Unison?
Following on from a recent question regarding 'unison', my research comes up with some diverse explanations.

'Perfect Unison' itself is two or more instruments playing the same pitch, when the harmonics of those will produce a far different sound (although several violins, for example, could play in unison, and sound very different from just one).

'Unison' could mean two or more instruments playing the same note name, but an octave or other octave copies of that same note.

'Rhythmic Unison' is two or more instruments playing simultaneously in the same rhythm, but using different pitches.


All quite varying and somewhat nebulous explanations of 'unison'.
Is one correct, or are they all correct?

Unison can also mean one instrument playing two copies of the same pitch. Members of the strings family can do this fairly easily. I think your question may not get a satisfying answer because I doubt there is an “exact” definition. Few words have “exact” definitions in English. Same as there’s no “exact” piano or forte dynamic level.

@ToddWilcox words not having an exact definition that applies in all contexts is a feature of human language generally, not only English.  For an example in Italian, consider piano, which (ignoring the musical instrument) can mean soft, flat, plain, plane, plan, level, or floor/store(e)y.

@ToddWilcox - the vast majority of words in English have pretty exact definitions - hence so many words! Piano and forte are relative, unlike unison, so cannot, by definition, be "exact".

@Elements In Space - not convinced the question involves intervals per se.

@Tim Perfect unison, perfect octave, etc. are intervals aren’t they?

"the vast majority of words in English have pretty exact definitions" - uh, citation needed! It's hugely common for words to have a tight specific meaning in the context of a particular field, and a much looser general meaning in common use. Is a strawberry a berry? It depends!

@ElementsInSpace - of course! But the question is focused on the term unison with regard to other aspects, I think.

Then you can add tags for them too; I suppose you could add the [rhythm] tag.

I hope you get the "exact" answer you're looking for, and thereby prove me wrong and get your answer at the same time.

@AakashM is correct.  Is a violin a lute?  In organology, the answer is "yes"; pretty much everywhere else, the answer is "no."  More broadly, even outside the phenomenon of jargon, terms of art, and field-specific technical definitions, a word's meaning can shift with context.  You can say you'll "run" to shop even if you're going to walk or drive; blind people can say "see you later"; a restaurant may be "open" even though its doors are "closed"; there are "hills" that are both higher and more prominent than some "mountains."

@phoog - loads of semantics here! When a door is closed, it needs opening to go to the other side (I nearly said through it...). And when it's closed, vice versa.  Run to the shops - never heard it! I'd bet that 90% of words in English have specific meanings, though. Bet, words, English, specific, meaning, all do in that last sentence...

@tim you make it too easy! "Bet" = the second letter of the Hebrew alphabet; "word" = a unit of computer storage, often equal to two bytes; "English" = side spin, in snooker and similar games; "specific" = relating to a physical property of a unit mass; "meaning" = intention. Or do you mean a specific meaning in a given context, in which case... well, that's my point!

@AakashM - point taken! But in my question/comment, it's apparent that the context is strictly a musical one - not talking about marriage, coupling for a joint, an organisation for trades, etc., etc., etc...

The meaning will vary with context, as is true of most words.
In most contexts, "unison" means "the same pitch in the same octave."  However, as Laurence notes, doubling in octaves is often described as "unison," particularly if a soprano or alto (or several) is singing an octave above a tenor or bass (or several).  It would also not be unreasonable in certain instrumental contexts, especially when it is a large portion of the ensemble or even the entire ensemble.  If it is a small number of instruments, a more precise statement such as "the flute and violin in octaves" or something like that is perhaps more likely.
"Perfect unison" could refer to the precision of the tuning, but without context suggesting this, the first thing that comes to my mind is the interval between any pitch and itself, in contrast to an augmented unison, which is the interval between, for example, C and C♯.  Like any perfect interval, it may be somewhat out of tune (but unlike perfect fourths and fifths it is unlikely to be tempered!).
"Rhythmic unison," while also not an unreasonable phrase, is probably less likely than "homophony" in many contexts; I think most people would be more likely to say "playing the same rhythm" than "in rhythmic unison."

The term "rhytmic unison" would seem most appropriate if one had e.g. multiple percussionists who each had a high tom and a low tom, and who all struck their high toms together, and all struck their low toms together, but whose high and low toms weren't tuned identically.

Yes, the distinction between same-pitch unison and doubling at the octave is often ignored.  You must be prepared to find 'unison' used to describe both, though you might wish to be more specific if it's YOU doing the describing!
'Rhythmic unison' is something else.  It will never be described simply as 'Unison'.

The general meaning includes descriptions like: harmonious, togetherness, synchronized, agreement, etc.
In music the primary meaning is: exact same pitch.
If you get into the details of interval naming, "unison" implies "perfect unison". "Diminished unison", "augmented unison", etc. then are not exactly "unisons" but sub-categories. Interval-wise you can point out that any kind of unison interval will pitches sharing the same pitch letter and octave number.
I bundle all that up into an idea of "sameness."
But, perfect sameness is an abstract idea. No two things in the physical world can be exactly the same, otherwise you couldn't distinguish them to be able to number them a quantity of two! At a certain point the mind accepts some things as similar enough to be called the same. There is flexibility in the sense of exact sameness. I believe that flexibility of sameness is the reason for the flexible meaning of "unison" in music.
When talking about ensemble playing "in unison" means playing in perfect unisons or perfect octaves.
Rhythmic unison means playing the same rhythm.

What about identical twins..? Or anything off the assembly line producing thousands of identical objects?

@Tim items off an assembly line are never exactly the same, people build their careers on trying to make it as reliable as possible. Tolerances may be very tight for human eyes but in the nanometer scale things drift all the time. We have just become very good at making them so close it's hard to see them as different but to someone running a machine they very much are. This may be analogous to music, a UNISON is when the fundamental frequencies line up and are more or less the same, but to what degree of accuracy? In tune has a bit of a buffer zone either side of 'perfect'.

"Identical" twin are not remotely the exact same. Not in the mathematical/abstract sense. If you're looking for a more artistic perspective, Marcel Duchamp used a term - infrathin - to signify the distinction between mass produce objects. https://www.artandpopularculture.com/Infrathin
